# Breeze and extraMetadata

Tags: breeze

I have a strange behavior regarding the extraMetadata (I am using OData)
1. I have created a clone function - I am creating new manager and importing into in an entity which I perform the operation

```
 ctor.prototype.clone = function() {
        var clonedManager = this.entityAspect.entityManager.createEmptyCopy(),
            exportData = this.entityAspect.entityManager.exportEntities([this], true), //export it to the new manager
            cloned;
        clonedManager.importEntities(exportData);
        cloned = clonedManager.getEntityByKey(this.entityAspect.getKey());
        return cloned;

    };
```

how ever I had to add

```
cloned.entityAspect.extraMetadata = this.entityAspect.extraMetadata;
```

cause I saw that it isn't being exported/imported

1. when I get entities using expand, those entities don't hold extraMetadata;

and without the extraMetadata I cannot commit the changes - as I get exception

Answer (score 0):

As of BreezeJs version 1.4.13, available now, this has been fixed.